# Problem with strtok and segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I have two helper functions to break up strings in the format of decimal prices ie. "23.00", "2.30"

Consider this:

```
char price[4] = "2.20";

    unsigned getDollars(char *price)
    {
       return atoi(strtok(price, "."));
    }

    unsigned getCents(char *price)
    {
       strtok(price, ".");
       return atoi(strtok(NULL, "."));
    }
```

Now when I run the below I get a segmentation fault:

```
printf("%u\n", getDollars(string));
printf("%u\n", getCents(string));
```

However when I run them seperately without one following the other, they work fine. What am I missing here? Do I have to do some sort of resetting of strtok??

**My solution:**

With the knowledge about strtok I gained from the answer I chose below, I changed the implementation of the helper functions so that they copy the passed in string first, thus shielding the original string and preventing this problem:

```
    #define MAX_PRICE_LEN 5 /* Assumes no prices goes over 99.99 */

unsigned getDollars(char *price)
{
   /* Copy the string to prevent strtok from changing the original */
   char copy[MAX_PRICE_LEN];
   char tok[MAX_PRICE_LEN];

   /* Create a copy of the original string */
   strcpy(copy, price);

   strcpy(tok, strtok(copy, "."));

   /* Return 0 if format was wrong */
   if(tok == NULL) return 0;
   else return atoi(tok);
}

unsigned getCents(char *price)
{
   char copy[MAX_PRICE_LEN];
   char tok[MAX_PRICE_LEN];
   strcpy(copy, price);

   /* Skip this first part of the price */
   strtok(copy, ".");
   strcpy(tok, strtok(NULL, "."));

   /* Return 0 if format was wrong */
   if(tok == NULL) return 0;
   else return atoi(tok);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `strtok()` modifies the input string, you run into problems when it fails to find the delimiter in the `getCents()` function after you call `getDollars()`.

Note that `strtok()` returns a null pointer when it fails to find the delimiter.  Your code does not check that `strtok()` found what it was looking for - which is always risky.

---

Your update to the question demonstrates that you have learned about at least some of the perils (evils?) of `strtok()`.  However, I would suggest that a better solution would use just `strchr()`.

First, we can observe that `atoi()` will stop converting at the '`.`' anyway, so we can simplify
`getDollars()` to:

```
unsigned getDollars(const char *price)
{
    return(atoi(price));
}
```

We can use `strchr()` - which does not modify the string - to find the `'.'` and then process the text after it:

```
unsigned getCents(const char *price)
{
    const char *dot = strchr(price, '.');
    return((dot == 0) ? 0 : atoi(dot+1));
}
```

Quite a lot simpler, I think.

---

One more gotcha: suppose the string is 26.6; you are going to have to work harder than the revised `getCents()` just above does to get that to return 60 instead of 6.  Also, given 26.650, it will return 650, not 65.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've taken it on board.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
char price[4] = "2.20";
```

leaves out the nul terminator on `price`. I think you want this:

```
char price[5] = "2.20";
```

or better:

```
char price[] = "2.20";
```

So, you will run off the end of the buffer the second time you try to get a token out of `price`. You're just getting lucky that `getCents()` doesn't segfault every time you run it.

And you should almost always make a copy of a string before using `strtok` on it (to avoid the problem that Jonathan Leffler pointed out).

Comment: I think that both answers/problems are factors.  Mine is the generic problem with (re)using `strtok()` on the same string. Yours is a special case with this particular non-string.