# Strtok segfault

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strtok giving Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385697/strtok-giving-segmentation-fault)

Why do i get segfault using this code ?

```
void test(char *data)
{
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(data, " ,.-"); // segfault
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    }

    return NULL;
}

char *data = "- This, a sample string.";
test(data);
```

Comment: This has been asked [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385697/strtok-giving-segmentation-fault) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925405/problem-with-strtok-and-segmentation-fault) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272876/cs-strtok-and-read-only-string-literals).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`strtok()` modifies the original string. You are passing it a **constant** source string that cannot be modified.

Try this instead:

```
char *data = strdup("- This, a sample string.");
test(data);
```

Comment: Or simply `char data[] = "- This, a sample string.";`

Comment: The modified code will demonstrate a version that won't crash because the compile time string literal is copied to a new heap allocated buffer allowing strtok to work.

Comment: That's going to create a memory leak though, unless you remember to free data after you are done.

Comment: ...and the alternative I suggest won't crash either, because the compile-time string literal is copied to a new stack allocated buffer.

Comment: Also note that `strdup` is not part of ANSI C, but POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

[`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) modifies the string. You are passing a pointer to read-only data (a string constant).

Try using a char array.

```
char data[] ="- This, is a sample string."
test(data);
```