# implement split string by strtok in C - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: android, c, string, gcc

Here is a method to implement split string by `strtok` in C.

```
void split(char** dest, char* src, const char* del){
    char* token = strtok(src, del);
    while(token!=NULL){
       *dest++ = token;
       token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
}
```

I tried to test this function by `main()` . The test device is asus T100(32bit OS, x64 processor) compiled by Cygwin with gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)

```
int main(void){
    char* str="/storage/SD:/storage/USB1";
    const char* del=":";
    char* arr[2];
    split(arr, str, del);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**, why?

The `sizeof(char*)` is **4bytes** on this test device.

If I modify

`char* str="/storage/SD:/storage/USB1";`

to

`char str[]="/storage/SD:/storage/USB1";`

everything run as expected.

Comment: The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function *modifies* the string you pass to it, and as you pass a pointer to a string literal which is *constant* you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strtok segfault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100214/strtok-segfault)

Comment: Thanks for the related link. And thanks yours answer. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Hsin-Hsiang Questions asked here not for the purpose to be deleted.:)

Comment: OK. I selected your answer to close this question:) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals in C and C++ are immutable. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour. Function strtok changes the string passed to it as argument. Replace this declaration

```
char* str = "/storage/SD:/storage/USB1";
```

with

```
char str[] = "/storage/SD:/storage/USB1";
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

And from the description of function `strtok`

> 4 The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is
>   contained in the current separator string. If no such character is
>   found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to
>   by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer.
>   **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character, which terminates the current token.** The strtok function saves a
>   pointer to the following character, from which the next search for a
>   token will start.

Take also into account that function main shall have return type `int`.

```
int main( void )
```