# splitting char *array using strtok giving runtime error

Tags: c, parsing, split, strtok, scanf

My code is pretty simple(just splitting an array) but since I don't have a c compiler, I'm compiling it online on http://ideone.com. However, it gives runtime error no matter what and I've also tried parsing with sscanf but in vain. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct{
   char *header;
   char *body;
}AT_msg_Data;
static char *__rx_data = "AT+CGMI\r";
int main(){
    AT_msg_Data *data;
    printf("In main");
    data->header = strtok(__rx_data,"+");
    data->body = strtok(NULL,"+");
    //also tried sscanf_s(data->body,"[^=]%s\r",at_comm,sizeof(at_comm),at_param,sizeof(at_param));
    printf("%s %s", data->header, data->body);
}
```

Comment: Try `static char *__rx_data = "AT+CGMI\r";` --> `static char __rx_data[] = "AT+CGMI\r";`

Comment: static char *__rx_data = "AT+CGMI\r"; // this is read only data try @CoolGuy 's approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strtok segfault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100214/strtok-segfault)

Comment: so many strdup questions so little interest in looking if the question was previously posted

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `strtok()` on a string literal, because string literals are constant. Generally it's safer to declare pointers to string literals with the `const` qualifier, to ensure the compiler will warn you when the program tries to modify the pointee.

You need to make your string an array instead of a pointer to a string literal, like this

```
static char __rx_data[] = "AT+CGMI\r";
```

this is an array of `9` bytes containing a string of `8` characters which you can modify, `strtok()` does modify it's arguments.

You also need to allocate space for your `struct` to be able to use it, you can do it in two ways, using `malloc()`

```
AT_msg_Data *data;
data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
if (data == NULL)
    return -1; /* failed to allocate memory -- exit the program */
```

or, just create an instance on the stack

```
AT_msg_Data data;
/*         ^ no star here */
```

and then access it's members with a `.` instead of `->`.

Another way which does not apply in this case because your string cannot be allocated dynamically, is to use `malloc()` or `strdup()`.

You could also use `strchr()` like this

```
const char *plus;
plus = strchr(__rx_data, '+');
if (plus != NULL)
{
    size_t length; /* maybe use `ptrdiff_t' here but just for illustration */
    length = plus - __rx_data;
    data->header = malloc(length + 1); 
    if (data->header != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(data->header, __rx_data, length);
        data->header[length] = '\0';
        data->body = strdup(plus + 1);
    }
    /* note: data->header can be `NULL' from here, so check that before using it */
    /*       this also applies to data->body */
}
```

This way you will not need to modify `__rx_data` which is better because it's a global variable and I assume you are going to reuse it. You should make your code safer by then redeclaring

```
static const char *const __rx_data = "AT+CGMI\r";
```

if you are going to use the `strchr()` approach.

With this declaration `__rx_data` cannot be reassigned or modified without the compiler complaining about it.

Your code will anyway fail later, because the  `'\0'` placed by `strtok()` at the position of the `+` sign will be overwritten with the `+` once you call `strtok()` again, `strtok()` keeps an internal buffer to restore the replaced characters that also makes it unsafe if your program is multithreaded.

Comment: Just to notice, his line `AT_msg_Data *data;` doesn't allocate memory for his structure to use. Could you at this to your answer, just for correctness pls.

Comment: @zeyorama I didn't even see that, when I saw `static char *__rx_data = "AT+CGMI\r"` I immediately started writing the answer since `strtok()` + *string literal* immediately triggered something in my brain.

Comment: @iharob  Sorry , I got bit rude (that comment sounded like you upvoted just because I argued .I didn't argued for that . What you said was your opinion and I had mine just that ). Sorry again !! :)

Comment: @iharob  I did undelete . Sorry for such behaviour .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sscanf` but first you need to allocate memory for `data` , `header` and `body`.

```
data = malloc(sizeof(AT_msg_Data));
if(data==NULL){
      // handle error
 }
data->header = malloc(10);
if(data->header==NULL){
      // handle error
 }

data->body = malloc(20);
if(data->body==NULL){
      // handle error
 }
```

And then use `sscanf` like this -

```
 if(sscanf(__rx_data,"%[^+]+%[^\r]\r",data->header,data->body)==2){     // if sscanf is successful 
   //do something
  }
```

Then after this `data->header` will conatain `AT` and `data->body` will have `CGMI` from the string.

Comment: This as it is, will probably invoke undefined behavior. It's a smart solution, but bear in mind you are giving this solution to a beginer, there is a huge chance of misusing `sscanf()` ignoring the return value of `malloc()` and thus posting another question *my program is crashing* or my neighbor is eating their dog.

Comment: Well if `sscanf()` `data->header` or `data->body` or bothe might be read without initialization, and also `malloc()` could return `NULL`. And alos, never `malloc()` for a constant value unless extremely necessary. Instead of `malloc(10)` or ... You could just redefine them in the `struct` definition like `char header[10]`. And always `malloc()` the exact ammount, there no infinite memroy.

Comment: @iharob  He is using pointers . At some or other point he will have to allocate memory . I agree on `malloc(10)` part . But what if need it to be done with pointers only  ?

Comment: @iharob  I just posted this as he said he tried `sscanf` also ,so assuming he would know about it .